# Anyone done ticket booking in IRCTC with "Connecting Journey Booking" option?

Tags: trains, bookings, irctc

Has anyone used "Connecting Journey Option" from IRCTC? If so, can you please provide/share following details:

1. Does it calculate telescopic distance?
2. What things must be kept in mind when booking the first ticket so that we can make use of this facility/option?
3. Is this applicable only for non-AC classes?

Thanks,
Hemant.

Comment: What do you mean by "telescopic distance"?

Comment: Hi Chris, This is one of the option provided by Indian Railways to avail minimum fare to travel to a destination. Assume you want to go from A to B but there is no direct train available. In such cases, you book ticket from A to C and then from C to B. The cost would be like 500 + 600 = 1100. When you go with "Connecting Journey option" (with Telescopic distance calculation), you get the same two trains but at reduced fare like 500 + 400 = 900.

Comment: Sharing an example route you may like to travel might also help everyone understand the use case.

Comment: Assume you want to travel from Chennai to Shimla via train and there is no direct train available yet. Your option is to book 1st ticket from Chennai to Delhi and then another ticket from Delhi to Shimla. In this case, how this ticket booking option can help or what are its advantages (online booking option).

Comment: I booked connecting booking from Junagadh to Vadodara, and Vadodara to Delhi but no benifit of telescopic distance charge was available like benifit on railway reservation window.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/122009)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I used "Connecting Journey Option" from IRCTC.

1. Does it calculate telescopic distance?
   No, This facility is just to provide you the refund incase you missed the connecting train. You still have 2-PNR tickets but linked.
   telescopic distance -> is for single PNR ticket with extended travel to other station.
2. What things must be kept in mind when booking the first ticket so that we can make use of this facility/option?
   -> Nothing. Steps are simple:
   Book 1st ticket as usual -> After booking 1st ticket, note down the PNR number -> Go to Trains tab, click on “Connecting Journey booking” -> Search for 2nd train availability -> click on 'Book now' -> Then it will ask you the PNR of 1st ticket (this step is for validation that if you are eligible for Connecting Journey booking or not) -> Enter 1st ticket PNR number -> Submit -> Then follow regular ticket booking steps.
3. Is this applicable only for non-AC classes?
   -> This is applicable for all Reservation classes, AC & non-AC.

Hope it helps for you. :)